# Sed to delete blank spaces

Tags: sed

Does anyone know how to use Sed to delete all blank spaces in a text file?  I haven been trying to use the "d" delete command to do so, but can't seem to figure it out

Answer (score 68):

### What kind of "space"?

To "delete all blank spaces" can mean one of different things:

1. delete all occurrences of the space character, code `0x20`.
2. delete all horizontal space, including the horizontal tab character, "`\t`"
3. delete all whitespace, including newline, "`\n`" and others

### The right tool for the job

If `sed` it not a requirement for some hidden reason, better use the right tool for the job.

The command `tr` has the main use in translating (hence the name "tr") a list of characters to a list of other characters. As an corner case, it can translate to the empty list of characters; The option `-d` (`--delete`) will delete characters that appear in the list.

The list of characters can make use of character classes in the `[:...:]` syntax.

1. `tr -d ' ' < input.txt > no-spaces.txt`
2. `tr -d '[:blank:]' < input.txt > no-spaces.txt`
3. `tr -d '[:space:]' < input.txt > no-spaces.txt`

### When insisting on `sed`

With sed, the `[:...:]` syntax for character classes needs to be combined with the syntax for character sets in regexps, `[...]`, resulting in the somewhat confusing `[[:...:]]`:

1. `sed 's/ //g' input.txt > no-spaces.txt`
2. `sed 's/[[:blank:]]//g' input.txt > no-spaces.txt`
3. `sed 's/[[:space:]]//g' input.txt > no-spaces.txt`

Comment: +1, POSIX notation for a blank space is the appropriate way to go.

Comment: Great hint to use tr for this task, works great. Only thing I had to adjust was that tr reads input from stdin, so what worked for me was `tr -d ' ' < input.txt > no-spaces.txt`.

Comment: @Sky's comment works in my macOS (not tested in Linux). Maybe the answer should be updated?

Comment: Thank a lot @Sky, that's indeed a bad error. I'll fix the three lines with `tr` now.  (Do you see it anywhere else?)

Comment: Note that even `[:space:]` does *not* strip all unicode spaces.

Answer (score 11):

You can use this to remove all whitespaces in `file`:

```
 sed -i "s/ //g" file
```

Comment: No dice.  I've tried a similar approach too.  Doesn't work

Comment: Do you want to delete whitespaces or tabs?

Comment: delete the whitespace

Comment: A simple test: `man sed | sed "s/ //g"`

Comment: I use `sed "s: ::g"` when i'm `grep`ing things, what's the difference between the two expression notations?

Comment: @starscream_disco_party: it‘s the same. You can replace all 3`/` with a different character, e.g.: `sed "ss ssg"`

Comment: You may want to try without the `-i` flag (`--in-place`) first — pipe `|` to `less` for instance.

Answer (score 4):

perhaps this way too late, but sed takes regular expression as input. '\s' is the expression of all whitespaces. So `sed s/'\s'//g` should do the job. cheers